# How to implement this subdirectory mapping in multisite?

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

Multisite Network with 2 sites:

- **Site 1**: `mysite.com/us/` (US)
- **Site 2**: `mysite.com/uk/` (UK)

Root domain: `mysite.com`

I basically only want TWO websites in my network. One for **US** and one for **UK**.

The problem is I currently have a 3rd site, `mysite.com`, which I have no use for. It could be a landing page which says '*select country*' but that seems unnecessary. It would be better if the person is just redirected to the US site by default.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested...but should work.  In your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ us [L]
```

(and yes...make a copy of your original .htaccess before you muck with it!)